# Нужно ли ставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятые в предложении: Он мог спать (,) по походной привычке(,) только на жёсткой ковровой подстилке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он мог спать, **по походной привычке**, только на жёсткой ковровой подстилке.

В структуру простого предложения "по походной привычке" не вписывается, обособляется в качестве **добавочного, поясняющего сообщения.**

Эти обстоятельства нельзя считать неоднородными, так как они связаны причинно-следственными отношениями.